# Backup software like Time Machine and CrashPlan combined?

Tags: software-recommendation, time-machine, backup

Is there a good backup software that combines Time Machine snapshot functionality on local level with CrashPlan remote backups as well? I am currently using both, but find both unsatisfactory.

My main problem with Time Machine is that it consumes a lot of resources and not playing nice. I have a pretty new beefy MacBook and I just know when TM starts running. Everything gets slow and it heats up. Check the processes, and sure enough backupd is at the top.

With CrashPlan I have less of a problem. It is generally very nice piece of software. But recently it is getting stuck for some reason and only know when I get notification by email that there were no backups for 2-3 days. Also it is quite bulky, and also UI is very ugly and not Mac-like.

Any recommendations?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd be interested in a good answer to this question as well. On the other hand, you'll likely get recommendations like 3-2-1 that recommend using at least 2 different backup methods, hence TM and CrashPlan actually being a pretty decent combination (although people will probably also recommend a bootable clone).

Comment: I don't know why your MBP slows down and heats up while doing a TM backup. What percentage of the CPU is being used by Backupd? Also, how full is the drive you are using as your TM disk and are you using this disk to store other files and not just TM backups? A relatively full TM drive may be doing lots of work deleting old backups. A TM drive containing other files may cause a slow TM backup if those files are in use at the time of the backup.

Comment: I'm not sure on % right now, but it was quit a lot, and surprising when I checked. Granted, I do have lots of other stuff open at the same time. But I feel like TM should be "nice" and not use so much resources if I am working on the computer with lots of resources already in use.

Yes, the disk is pretty full. 35 GB of 1 TB available. But my understanding is that TM is supposed to manage space itself. E.g. it fills it up and then deletes old stuff. There are no other settings.

The drive also has another partition with other files, but it's mostly just archival stuff and I never access it.

Answer (score 6):

I am a big fan of Arq (http://www.haystacksoftware.com/arq/), which works just like TimeMachine but with remote backups on Amazon S3/Glacier.

Comment: I have around 2 TB of data that I backup to Amazon Cloud using Arq. At about $60/year for unlimited storage, you can't beat it with a stick. Granted, you also have to buy the Arq client, but that is a fixed cost and well worth it. It's excellent software.

Comment: Also, Arq is not _exactly_ like Time Machine which actually backs up **everything** on your Mac minus temporary files. Arq is designed to back up your home directory which includes your Library folder but sifts out the same temp files that TM does. You can also include the contents of other folders and/or drives and exclude unwanted files as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try out SuperDuper!, a free-if-you-want-it-and-paid-if-you-want-additional-features app. Go to the nearest electronic store and grab yourself a external hard drive if you don't have one. (Judging by crashplan and time machine backups, I assume you have one.)

When you come inside SuperDuper, then click from, and then choose your hard drive. At the to, click disk image.

Then, make a disk image on the new external drive or time capsule or whatever, and then name it the time and date at your time zone. Then click copy.

Now, every time you launch the app, make sure you make another disk image to prevent overwriting.

Answer (score 0):

Time Machine supports remote backups with some limitations (many of which have workarounds). I've been using it over LAN for a while with no problems and not too much CPU usage, so I'm not sure why you're having CPU usage problems.

The best alternative IMO is Carbon Copy Cloner. It supports remote backups and gives you tons of customization including fully bootable backups (unlike TM), though it has no "snapshot" feature like Time Machine. It was freeware but is now $30, BUT you can still download the old freeware version (3.4.7) from [here](http://www.bombich.com/download.html). It's no longer supported and claims that it's meant for 10.4 and 10.5, but I've been using it forever in 10.6 through 10.9 with no problems and have relied on its bootable backups several times.

Another answer mentions SuperDuper!. I haven't used it in a long time, but I remember it not being as good. Can't hurt to try both.